# QT - No default version found Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with the Qt in Visual Studio 2015. I open a qt project, but when i press on the file.ui, i recive the following error:No default Qt version found, even if I have the path setted correctly. Can somebody help me, please?
[image: qt-options-path]

Comment: Why don't you open it in Qt Creator?

Comment: what OS are you running?

Answer (score -2):

Since  you  are  working  in a Visual Environment, kindly  download this QT installer:

http://caesar.ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/qt.io/qtproject/archive/qt/5.9/5.9.0/qt-

Moreover, you must have installed  QT Visual Studio Extension. My environment is Visual Studio 2015, from the VSTOOLQT extension located on the menu navigated to the directory where QT is installed, then navigate to C:\Qt\Qt5.9.0\5.9\msvc2015_64.

It will solve the issue.

Comment: Your link is not working. Moreover, do not link a particular mirror and version.